# Conditional WHERE in SQL clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

I need to put a `WHERE` condition, depending of the value of a parameter.

Here is the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE 
   T1.SalesPerson IN (
      SELECT VendorName FROM dbo.TB_grpVendor WHERE GroupName = @Group
   ) AND 
   (
     T0.DocDate >= @DateBegin AND T0.DocDate <= @DateEnd OR 
     T0.DocDate >= @DateBegin2 AND T0.DocDate <= @DateEnd2
   ) AND 
   T0.CANCELED <> 'Y'
```

Variable `@Group` is a parameter. If it equals to `"ALL"`, I need to ignore the first part of the `WHERE`. How can I do this?

Comment: Suggested reading: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `OR`:

```
where (@Group = 'ALL' OR
       EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM dbo.TB_grpVendor 
               WHERE VendorName = T1.SalesPerson AND GroupName = @Group
               )
       ) AND
       . . .
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this functionality with the logical `or` operator:

```sql
WHERE (@Group = 'ALL' OR 
       T1.SalesPerson IN (SELECT VendorName FROM dbo.TB_grpVendor WHERE GroupName = @Group)) AND 
      (T0.DocDate >= @DateBegin AND T0.DocDate <= @DateEnd OR  
       T0.DocDate >= @DateBegin2 AND T0.DocDate <= @DateEnd2 ) AND 
      (T0.CANCELED <> 'Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this would be better handled with a JOIN

```
INNER JOIN dbo.TB_grpVendor GV on T1.SalesPerson = GV.VendorName
    AND @GroupName IN ('All', GV.GroupName)
WHERE
(
    T0.DocDate >= @DateBegin AND T0.DocDate <= @DateEnd OR 
    T0.DocDate >= @DateBegin2 AND T0.DocDate <= @DateEnd2
)
AND T0.CANCELED <> 'Y'
```